# Geo complete for ReactJS

Tags: geolocation, reactjs, geocomplete, reactjs-native

I need longitude and latitude, for that user need to enter their places and then depend on that location I need to take lat and lang.

I searched the internet and I found some geo-auto-complete libraries but I'm not able to use them, is there any good library for autocomplete for ReactJS?
I'm using ReactJS and JSX with browser.min.js to design a search page!

I'm new to ReactJS, please help. if there is any library can u tell me the basic implementation! learning reactJS on the web. so I'm confused with this stuff.

thank you

Comment: You can use the normal google maps api, to retrieve the results and render them in a list under the input element. As an idea..

Comment: Can you tell me the link of example for that. So that I can check an learn from there